# Issues using a standalone application with py2app on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, py2app, hashlib

I have build my python script to an app on Mac with py2app. I can open the file on the Mac that builds the app. However, if I want to open the app on another Mac, I get some error messages. I don't used the system installation of Mac to build the app, instead I used the homebrew python installation. 
The error messages are the following:

```
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
from hashlib import md5
ImportError: cannot import name md5
```

I am very new on the Mac OS. I used Python 2.7.
Can anyone tell me how to solve the problem?